# How to combine an array of unique objects into a single object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ecmascript-6

I have an array that looks like this:

```
const myArray = [
  { 'John': 50 },
  { 'Adam': 29 },
  { 'Jack': 40 }
]
```

How do I convert the array into an object that looks like this?

```
const convertedObject = {
  'John': 50,
  'Adam': 29,
  'Jack': 40
}
```

Comment: Start with an empty object and use `Object.assign` on it several times.

Answer (score 2):

You can spread the array into `Object.assign()`:

```js
const myArray = [
  { 'John': 50 },
  { 'Adam': 29 },
  { 'Jack': 40 }
]

const convertedObject = Object.assign({}, ...myArray)

console.log(convertedObject)
```

Comment: Note that this leads to a stack overflow on arrays that are large enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.reduce()` for that:

```js
const myArray = [
    {'John':50},
    {'Adam':29},
    {'Jack':40}
]
var res = myArray.reduce((acc, item) => {
  var key = Object.keys(item)[0];
  acc[key] = item[key];
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(res);
```